# Taylor Series Approximation of the Variance Function

Tags: statistics, taylor-expansion, machine-learning

The problem setting is offline learning from bandit feedback data. Given a context vector $x$, a policy chooses an action $a$, with policy defined as $h_w(y \vert x)$, where $w$ is the 'learnable' parameter for the policy. The offline data is collected using the logging policy $h_0(y \vert x)$. The objective is to optimize the mean of the following terms $u_{w}^i = \delta_i \frac{h_w(y_i \vert x_i)}{h_0(y_i \vert x_i)}$.
I am following a paper, ["Counterfactual Risk Minimization: Learning from Logged Bandit Feedback"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.02362.pdf), which adds a sample variance term to the objective defined above, $\sqrt{\text{Var}(u)}$.

Now the authors approximate the $\sqrt{\text{Var}(u)}$ term using the first-order Taylor-series approximation around the parameter $w$ (Section 5.1, proposition 1), which they define as:

$\sqrt{\text{Var}(u)} \leq A_{w_0} \sum_{n=1}^{n} u_{w}^i +B_{w_0}  \sum_{n=1}^{n} (u_{w}^i)^2 + A_{w_0}  $.

I cannot derive the taylor series approximation which matches the term derived in the paper. In my understanding, since the taylor series approximation is w.r.t the parameter $w$, there should be $w$ and $w_0$ terms in the expansion, not sure how $u_{w}^i$ terms appear in the derivation.

Comment: Are there possible connections with [Gram-Charlier expansions](https://indico.cern.ch/event/74919/contributions/1246262/attachments/1047650/1493312/Heavy_Ions_2009_Michiel_de_Kock_Edgeworth.pdf) ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks for your reply. I am not familiar with Gram-Charlier expansions. In the paper, authors write that the expansion is from a first-order taylor series approximation.